# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named

Tags: flask, pycharm

I have created a project in PyCharm, and i have main.py as mentioned in the below image,
content of the main.py is,

`from folder import app #folder is actually the directory which has static, templates and python scripts`

When i execute main.py it fails with `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named # functions imported in __init__.py`

**init**.py holds all the routes and app is also initialised in the same file

But when **init**.py is executed, the application runs fine.

[image]

Any suggestion would be helpful to execute the a application from main.py as this will be used in the deployment

Answer (score 0):

The modules has to me imported along with the directory name in **init**.py

`from Folder.module import *`

You should have your own folder name and module name